# Is there any way to suppress attribute a isn't defined error in stringTemplate?

Tags: java, log4j, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

When setting up a template, if the attribute keys are not set into the ST object it throws the error :

```
         context [anonymous] 11:27 attribute  isn't defined
```

is there any way to suppress this error or flag to not to show error in logs.i'm using log4j to log my log is filed with **attribute  isn't defined** error what should i do remove this from log?

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own [STErrorListener](http://www.stringtemplate.org/api/org/stringtemplate/v4/STErrorListener.html) or use [ErrorBuffer](http://www.stringtemplate.org/api/org/stringtemplate/v4/misc/ErrorBuffer.html) to catch the errors and then iterate over the error messages and decide if you want to write it to the log or not depending its type.

Comment: Thank You.
I feel this needs an STGroup (stGroup.errMgr=...) , for ST directly, I've not found a way to add an errorListener, unfortunatelly

Comment: UPDATE: even with ST there can an ErrorHandler be added. Just construct the ST with an Group, which points to an error handler - C'est tout! :)

Comment: new ErrorManager(new STErrorListener() { @Override public void runTimeError(STMessage msg) {  if (msg.error == ErrorType.NO_SUCH_ATTRIBUTE)  ... }; ... }